# Can you use this.setState in a constructor object inside a react component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, constructor

I want this firebase on value event listener to be running inside this component at all times listening for changes in the database to then update the state. I was looking at examples and I only found that I can add this particular firebase event listener inside the constructor object. However, when I set the state I receive an error as such `null is not an object(evaluating this.setState)`. Any Ideas on how I can get around this?

constructor(props) {

```
    super(props);
    this.props = props;
    this.actions = commentActions;
    this.state = {
      comments: [],
      loadingComments: true,
      lastCommentUpdate: null,
      review: props.review ? props.review : null,
      login: null,
      id: props.id
    };

    this.scrollIndex = 0;


    database.ref("comments/").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      console.log('DATA: ', typeof snapshot)
      // console.log(this.state.comments )

      this.setState({
        comments:[...this.state.comments, snapshot]
      })
    })

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're problem is here:

```
database.ref("comments/").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log('DATA: ', typeof snapshot)
  // console.log(this.state.comments )
  this.setState({
    comments:[...this.state.comments, snapshot]
  })
})
```

**this bit**: function(snapshot) , is binding the "this" context to the caller, which is ".on" (guessing). So, we have to remove that. Make sure you call "this" in the context of the constructor, by changing it to an anonymous function, which doesn't have a "this" context of its own.. SO, the "this" is gotten from the surrounding object.

**Change to**: This allows for the "this" context to to be owned by parent object.

```
database.ref("comments/").on("value",(snapshot) => {
  console.log('DATA: ', typeof snapshot)
  console.log(this.state.comments )

  this.setState({
    comments:[...this.state.comments, snapshot]
  })
})
```

IF this dooesn't work, then I assume "this" is not defined yet, within the confines of the constructor call, so you'll probably have better luck putting it in "ComponentDidMount" lifecycle method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` inside a constructor, and if it is called after the end of the current execution stack as it would with a database call, it would trigger a re-render. So yes your approach would work if not for the other errors. I do however recommend doing data fetching in the `componentDidMount` method of a component as sited in the [React.Component documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.